# Zookeeper startup on system reboot error

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have installed zookeeper on my Linux server ubuntu 12.04 in some folder like abc/zookeeper/zkserver/bin/zkserver.sh start. this works fine and starts the server as expected but when i put this zkserver.sh file in /etc/init.d folder and copy the file in rc2.d folder for the reason to start-up zookeeper on system reboot. and when i run this command /etc/init.d/zkserver.sh start this is giving errors like: 
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /etc/init.d/../etc/zookeeper/zoo.cfg
grep: /etc/init.d/../etc/zookeeper/zoo.cfg: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory `': No such file or directory
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED

Answer (score 0):

The zkServer.sh is dependent on a certain directory structure and certain files being present. It is not supposed to be moved in isolation like that. It is also not supposed to be used as an init script.

Check if your zk download comes with the init script. Try looking at src/packages/rpm/init.d/zookeeper or similar, and use that one instead.

Comment: Thank you for the update . As you have mentioned I have looked into the same directory and i have found that script but can explain more about this i.e how can i trigger that script on startup the system.?

Comment: It depends on the system you are using. In your case, once you have your proper /etc/init.d/zookeeper script in place, you can start and stop it as a service manually. You need to take an extra step to make it start automatically at boot. This also depends on your system. Take a look at this, for example: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20357/how-can-i-make-a-script-in-etc-init-d-start-at-boot